# What is wrong with the JavaScript Mapping Below?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

```
const myAssetMap = {
  General: {
    name: 'Common',
    bkgHex: '#eee',
    fontHex: '#aaa',
  },
 ...

const getAsset = (name, type) => {
  return myAssetMap.name.type;
}

console.log( getAsset('General', 'name') );
```

This is erring with: `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'type' of undefined`

Comment: Change this `return myAssetMap.name.type;`
to this `return myAssetMap[name][type]`

Comment: It should be `myAssetMap[name][type]`

Comment: Strange, that is still erring with `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'svg' of undefined`

Comment: @AnApprentice In that case, you might be calling `getAsset('Something', 'svg')` where `Something` does not exist in `myAssetMap`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to access the keys `name` and `type`, not the keys stored in the variables. Use bracket notation instead:

```
return myAssetMap[name][type];
```

Comment: ya idk, it works when type is 'name' but when type is 'bkgHex' it errors w Cannot read property 'bkgHex' of undefined

Comment: @AnApprentice How is that possible given the object at the Question? Can you reproduce what you are describing at stacksnippets?